# Node-schedule sending duplicate cron jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, cron

I'm using [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/), to send one notification over the weekend, and for some reason, it's sending out duplicate notifications even though I'm explicitly preventing it from doing that.

```
cron.schedule('0 5 23 * * 7', someFunction); is what I call.
```

someFunction is below:

```
module.exports = async () => {
  const users = await User.find({ isSpecialUser: true });

  users.forEach(async user => {
    const notifications = await Notification.find({ to: user._id, read: false });
const duplicated = notifications.find(notification =>
  momnet(notification.createdAt).format('YYYY/MM/DDD') === momnet().format('YYYY/MM/DDD'));
if(!duplicated) {
  await notificationManager.notify(user._id,
    'Reminder', 'sendsomenotification');
}
  });
};
```

I think the cron is written correctly, but not sure why this scheduler is being called twice and the user is seeing two notifications. Is it a server-side issue?

Comment: Is `someFunction` called exactly twice? Also: have you made sure you only run one instance of your scheduler?

Comment: no we're using heroku and it only calls it one instance in the scheduler. is it a possible Heroku bug?

Comment: What kind of Procfile / deployment setup you have with heroku ps? They may be relevant

Comment: they're pretty standard - I added them here https://pastebin.com/sfpvUCZL

Comment: How about `heroku ps`? Are you sure you are running exactly one copy of the app?